# What is the right way to customize Alfresco 4.2.2 Enterprise?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-maven, alfresco-enterprise

Some times ago, I used Alfresco 5.2 CE. When I needed to develop some kind of customization, I used the [Alfresco Maven SDK](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.2/concepts/sdk-getting-started.html) with three different [Maven archetypes](https://maven.apache.org/archetypes), it was:

- Alfresco Repository AMP;
- Alfresco Share AMP;
- Alfresco all-in-one (AIO).

By using this SDK I developed [AMP files](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.2/concepts/dev-extensions-packaging-techniques-amps.html) that overlaid on either the `alfresco.war` or `share.war` by using the module management tool (MMT):

```
...
java -jar bin/alfresco-mmt.jar install amps/some-customization-share.amp tomcat/webapps/share.war -force
java -jar bin/alfresco-mmt.jar install amps/some-customization-repo.amp tomcat/webapps/alfresco.war -force
...
```

Now I am using Alfresco 4.2.2 Enterprise and looking for the right way to do the same things that I did with Alfresco 5.2 CE.

Let's say, I want to develop a two tier [Spring Surf](http://docs.alfresco.com/community5.0/concepts/surf-fwork-intro.html) customization that can remotely connect to different repositories. Or, for example, I need to develop a new Spring Surf page for a site, or just make some little changes in some [FTL](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/index.html)-template.

What is the right way? Is there a similar SDK for Alfresco 4.2.2 Enterprise?

I would be very grateful for the information. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Maven-based Alfresco 3.0 SDK is compatible with Alfresco 4.2, both Enterprise and Community Edition.

Comment: Yep, here is the reference mention : http://docs.alfresco.com/5.2/references/sdk-whats-new.html#sdk-whats-new__2
Keep in mind that "A small one line change is required in module.properties for 4.2.x support."

Comment: I would add a downside, it seems that only 4.2.7 is supported, not 4.2.2.

Comment: If the 3.0 SDK won't work with 4.2.2 then you can always use the 2.x version of the SDK, then upgrade to 3.0 when you upgrade Alfresco. Upgrading a project from SDK 2.x to SDK 3.x is not a big deal.